# How can you use the variables in a seperate class in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, class

I'm practicing Java programming, and while I was going through class and array, I found myself stuck at printing arrays. I'm trying to use the variables that I made in a separate class, but I'm not sure how to add the values and how to print them out.

```
class A {
int a;
String b;}


public class testnew {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A[] test = new A[100];
    test[0] = new A();
    test[0].a = 1;
    test[0].b = "2";
    System.out.println(test[0].a + test[0].b);
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. Your code prints the number 1 ... and then directly prints the String "2". So you get `12` printed to you. But as you havent told us what you expect to happen, as said: we cant help you, unless you tell us what you consider the problem here.

Comment: You'd want to look into how to implement `toString()` for `A` or how to loop over array elements and print each one separately (or build a string first and print it after the loop).

Answer (score 0):

It's not about arrays or other classes at all. Here, keep it simple:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 1;
    String b = "2";
    System.out.println(a + b);
}
```

This prints `12`. And, if I understand your question correctly, your question is: "Er, I want it to print 3 instead". Thus, forget about the array part and the other class part - those bits are working just fine. It's the job of adding `1` and `"2"` that is confusing you.

Java is strongly typed. `"2"` is a string. The fact that this string contains a numeric character **does not change anything**. It's a string. Period. Strings act the same way regardless of what its contents are.

In java, the `+` operator is actually a single symbol that does two completely different, totally unrelated things. A real guns and grandmas situation.

Which of the two utterly different things it means is decided, at compile time.

If either the lefthand or the righthand side is an expression of type string, the + means **string concatenation**.

If both left and right are numbers, it's **addition**.

Otherwise, it is an error.

Here, the lefthand side is an `int` (a number), and the righthand side is a string. Thus, the + means string concatenation, and the operation is performed by first transforming all relevant inputs to a string (so, 1 becomes `"1"`, and `"2"` remains `"2"`), and then concatenating these 2, producing `"12"`.

If you want to take a string and turn it into a number, you want:

```
int c = Integer.parseInt("2");
System.out.println(c); // 2
int d = 1 + c;
System.out.println(d); // 3
```

In the above code, `1` is a number, `c` is a number, thus, `+` now means addition, and so it goes: d is now 3, and not 12.